# use jquery to multiply data dynamically in a php/laravel loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

so i am using jQuery in a crud system where there is an input for quantity that multiplies the price stored in the database and then outputs it in the field next to it but it is outputting it in all the fields next to the input i tried everything but i am unable to do it, any one who can tell me whats wrong with my code,

[heres the real output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xP1XR.png)

[and this is the result i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8107.png)

this is my view file

```
            <?php 
                $i=1;
            ?>
    @foreach ($productData as $rsproductData)
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $i ?></td>
            <?php
                $i++;
            ?>
            <td class="d-none">{{$rsproductData->id}}</td>
            <td>{{$rsproductData->products}}</td>
            <td>{{$rsproductData->wholesale}}</td>
            <td>{{$rsproductData->price}}</td>
            <td><input type="number" class="form-control qtyChckInput mb-2" name="qty"></td>
            <td class="totalPrice" name="totalPrice">0</td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-success editModalBtn">Edit</button></td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-danger deleteModalBtn">Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
                <th>Item Total</th>
                <td id="itemTotal">0</td>
                <td></td><td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
                <th>10% discount on Item Total</th>
                <td id="itemDiscount">0</td>
                <td></td><td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
                <th>5% Tax on Item Total</th>
                <td id="itemTax">0</td>
                <td></td><td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
                <th>Grand Total</th>
                <td id="itemGrand">0</td>
                <td></td><td></td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
</tbody>
```

this is my js file

```
$('input[name*="qty"]').keyup(function()
    {
        $tr = $(this).closest('tr');

        var data = $tr.children("td").map(function () {
            return $(this).text();
        }).get();

        text = $(this).val();
        
        $(".totalPrice").html(data[4] * text)
        
        var itemTotal = $('.totalPrice').html();
        
        $('#itemTotal').html(itemTotal);

        var itemDiscount = itemTotal * (1 - 10 / 100);

        $('#itemDiscount').html(itemTotal - itemDiscount);

        var itemTax = itemTotal * (1 - 5 / 100);

        $('#itemTax').html(itemTotal - itemTax);

        var itemGrand = itemTax + itemDiscount - itemTotal;

        console.log(itemGrand);

        $('#itemGrand').html(itemGrand);
    });
```

Comment: fyi, `id` attributes **must** be unique on a page, you have multiple of the same `id`s due to the loop

Comment: i know i tried using class and everything but i can't seem to figure it out

Comment: "_i know_" Why produce/post invalid code then?

Comment: well code is valid it is using class you can see the code,
the issue is that i want it output value in the field next to it not all fields

Comment: `id="qtyInput"` and `id="totalPrice"` inside a `@foreach` makes this code "invalid" as said, duplicate `id`s

Comment: ok i removed the ids but the issue still exists

Comment: @brombeer is there a different way to do this if yes then kindly tel me thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using dynamic id/class for your HTML entities, below is a short calculation for your reference.

```
<tr>
    <td id="products_{{ $rsproductData->id }}">{{$rsproductData->products}}</td>
    <td id="wholesale_{{ $rsproductData->id }}">{{$rsproductData->wholesale}}</td>
    <td id="price_{{ $rsproductData->id }}" value="{{$rsproductData->price}}">{{$rsproductData->price}}</td>
    <td><input type="number" class="form-control qtyChckInput mb-2" data-product="{{ $rsproductData->product }}" name="qty"></td>
</tr>

<script>
    $('input[name*="qty"]').keyup(function()
    {
        var id = $(this).data('product');
        var price = $("#price_"+id).val();
        var quantity = $(this).val();
        // Short calucalation for example
        $('#itemGrand').html(price*quantity);
    });
</script>
```